# how to get fps value of games in android devices

Tags: android, frame-rate, dumpsys

Recently,i studied to how to record fps value of games in android devices.Finally,i found three ways to get the value.

- adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --latency SurfaceView
- adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo
- adb shell service call SurfaceFlinger 1013

When i compared with the value reorder with game engine,i found that value calculated by the third way was close ，the others were unstable(that means these values are almost unchanged).With the third way，the device needed to be root.Anyone can tell me about the difference between the three ways comprehensive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a few ways to get to most closely value and this lib help me with that:
https://github.com/friendlyrobotnyc/TinyDancer

edit: TinyDancer gives you a dynamic icon with current fps value